# Python 3 Installation Errors Ubuntu 22

Tags: 22.04, python3

When using pip install

```
python3 -m pip install
```

I get the error

```
AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'reader'
```

Python version installed is `python --version Python 3.10.12`

I am wondering is something is wrong with my Python installation/path.

Thank you.

Output of `python3 -c 'import sys;import csv;print(sys.version,csv.__all__)';echo /bin/python*` is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute '__all__'. Did you mean: '__file__'?
/bin/python /bin/python3 /bin/python3.10 /bin/python3.10-config /bin/python3.10-coverage /bin/python3-config /bin/python3-coverage /bin/python3-futurize /bin/python3-pasteurize /bin/python-argcomplete-check-easy-install-script3 /bin/python-argcomplete-tcsh3
```

Comment: 'csv' is a builtin python module so Python looks corrupt. Please [edit] your post with the output of `python3 -c 'import sys;import csv;print(sys.version,csv.__all__)';echo /bin/python*`. You could try reinstalling the affected file with `sudo apt reinstall libpython3.10-minimal`. I see you are trying to use pip. Please make sure to use virtualenv so that pip accidents do not break the system

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35341363/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-reader this could be the problem

Comment: I have just updated with the output

Comment: Based on that output, you should indeed follow moo's advice of renaming `csv.py` from your project. When you code Python, take care to not name the files the same name as builtin Python modules